# Get rid of mixed derivatives in stationary PDE using coordinate transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

[In this question the PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102089/second-order-pde-of-laplace-equation-form-but-with-mixed-derivatives-term)
$$u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz} + u_{zy} = 0,$$
was rewritten to the standard Laplace equation $\Delta u=0$ using a coordinate transform, in some sense similar how you can map an ellipse to a circle and vice versa. I was wondering if a similar technique can be applied to the PDE
$$-u_{xx} - u_{xy} - u_{yy}  + 5u = f.$$
Possibly with Neumann boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make change of variables: $\xi = y - \frac{x}2$, $\eta = \frac{x\sqrt{3}}2$, $v(\xi, \eta) = u(x, y)$. And you will get an equation
$$
5 v - \frac{3}4 \partial_\xi^2 v- \frac{3}4 \partial_\eta^2v = f,
$$
or
$$
\left(\Delta - \frac{20}3\right)v(\xi, \eta)=-\frac{4}3f(\xi, \eta).
$$
It is inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation. Such equations are studied separately from the Poisson and Laplace equations, but in a similar way.